# How to disable enter key in angular if condition does not match?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

If input is null enter key  should not call the function "generateCityDetailArray()" means it should be disabled, otherwise it should call the function "generateCityDetailArray()". How to achieve this?

```
<div class="form-group">
          <input type = "text" class="col2"  formControlName="pinCode" 
          [(ngModel)]="pinCode"  required (keyup.enter)="generatecityDetailArray()" maxlength="6" />
          <div *ngIf="f.pinCode.invalid && f.pinCode.touched"><strong class="text-danger" *ngIf="f.pinCode.errors?.required">Please enter the value!</strong></div>
</div>
```

Now, If I **click enter** in textbox, it is calling `"generateCityDetailArray()"` even when input is null. What required  is  if input is null and  If enter is clicked then it should give a message like "Plz Enter pincode", "generateCityDetailArray()" should not be called when input is null.

Answer (score 1):

why not just start method `generatecityDetailArray()` by

```
if (!this.pinCode) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: Because I am asked to use validator, person who has assigned task has said using If statement (any type of validation logic) in "generatecityDetailArray()" will not be standard reactive angular form approach.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of starting the `generatecityDetailArray()` method with a check if you have a value of `pinCode` is a great option. 
If you want to have your check performed in the template, you can also do the following:

```
(keyup.enter)="cityDetailForm.get('pinCode').invalid ? $event.preventDefault() : generatecityDetailArray()"
```

This is if you have only one validator setup for the pinCode formControl.
If you have multiple make the check `cityDetailForm.get('pinCode').errors?['required']`. 
Also this is assuming that `cityDetailForm` is your formGroup. I previously thought it was simply `f`, because of the `ngIf` check on your `div`. 
It would be best to have a getter in the component for this case, so it would be something like:

```
  get isCityDetailInValid(): boolean {
    return this.cityDetailForm.get('pinCode').errors?['required'];
    // or this.cityDetailForm.get('pinCode').invalid;
  }
```

Then your template would simply be:

```
(keyup.enter)="isCityDetailInValid ? $event.preventDefault() : generatecityDetailArray()"
```

Comment: Thanks @justchecking I want to check in template only, but by using this code "(keyup.enter)="pinCode ?? generatecityDetailArray()" , "generatecityDetailArray()" is not called even when value is entered

Comment: @Rajeev sorry, I didn't notice you're using `pinCode` as a formControl. `[(ngModel)]` threw me off. You don't need it if you're using a reactive form. As far as your professor's concern, it's a most common practice to check if your form input is valid in the method that works with your gathered data. If you have your validator setup to have your input field as `required` you can still do the check in the template. it will be something like `(keyup.enter)=f.pinCode.invalid ? generatecityDetailArray() : $event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: validator is set to have input field  required . But adding code did nothing , it is still same.  This code "(keyup.enter)=f.pinCode.invalid ? generatecityDetailArray() : $event.preventDefault()" didn't worked.

Comment: @Rajeev Actually should revert the condition, you want to call generatecityDetailArray() if there isn't an error, so it should be `f.pinCode.invalid ? $event.preventDefault() : generatecityDetailArray()`. This was a bit of pseudo code, please give more effort from your side. The complete solution should be 
`(keyup.enter)=cityDetailForm.get('pinCode').invalid ? $event.preventDefault() : generatecityDetailArray()`
This is if you have only one validator setup for the pinCode formControl. If you have multiple make the check `cityDetailForm.get('pinCode').errors?['required']` .

Answer (score 0):

if you have form control on input you can launch method only when input have no error

```
(keyup.enter)="pinCode.errors ? '' : generatecityDetailArray()"
```

If you want to display message to say you have to enter pincode you can use follwing syntaxe

```
 <div *ngIf="pinCode.errors?.['required']">
    Please Enter pincode.
  </div>
```

in your class you have to define getter and setter of the form control

```
get pinCode() { return this.cityDetailForm.get('pinCode'); }
```

here the doc about validators
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: I already have done that                                                                                                                              
  this.cityDetailForm = new FormGroup({
     pinCode: new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(1),Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]))

Comment: ok so what your remaining issue ? how to call generatecityDetailArray and form validation ?

Comment: Now, If I **click enter** in textbox, it is calling "generateCityDetailArray()" even when input is null. What required  is  if input is null and  If enter is clicked then it should give a message like "Plz Enter pincode", "generateCityDetailArray()" should not be called.

Comment: ok i edit my reply you can use `(keyup.enter)="pinCode.errors ? '' : generatecityDetailArray(ProjectName)"` to launch function only when pincode have no error

Comment: It is giving error "Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'string'. Also what should I write in **(ProjectName)**. Should I write form name?

Comment: forget projectname it's a bad copy paste call your function generatecityDetailArray()

Comment: in the doc there is the reply you have to set getter and setter on formcontrol. I add it to my reply `get pinCode() { return this.cityDetailForm.get('pinCode'); }`